# How to filter based on 3 different conditions (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

[image]

I have three selectors:

- multiselector (**genres**), for instance array id's of selected genres [14, 8, 6] and should check if the '**genre_id** exists in this array of ids.
- **year**, this should check the key value of '**release_year**'
- input field, which should check the key values of '**title**' and '**artist**'

default value when it is empty

1. multiselector(**genres**) --> []
2. year --> []
3. input field --> ''

**Keep in mind that it should also work when user only type input field only or only select genres**

In order to build a function I need to filter and check if that exist in the object key value.

[Click on the link to codesandbox to get a better understanding of this issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu10/music-app?file=/src/components/SearchResult/SearchResult.tsx)

```js
0: {id: 501437, artist: "Bob", title: "All In", release_year: 2014, genre_id: 14, …}
1: {id: 501649, artist: "Elina", title: "Veni paca to", release_year: 2014, genre_id: 8, …}
2: {id: 501895, artist: "Timbo", title: "I Should Have Known It", release_year: 2010, genre_id: 8, …}
3: {id: 502139, artist: "Wakanda", title: "Grove St. Party", release_year: 2011, genre_id: 6, …}
4: {id: 502992, artist: "Beyoncé", title: "Single Ladies (Put a Ring on It)", release_year: 2008, genre_id: 62,
```

So I was wondering how I can write a concise code that will filter everything. So if I write something like "bob", but select year '2013' it will not show anything and if I change year to '2014'. then 'Bob' 'All In' will show in the result.

```js
const selectedYear = 2014;
const inputValue = 'bob';
const selectedGenres = [14, 6, 8];

const filterRequirements = (data: any) => {
        if(selectedYear !== data.release_year) return false;
        return true;
    }
const filteredVideos = videoList.filter(filterRequirements);
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem and what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: filter based on input field and multiselector (array if ids)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try filter like below.

- Added condition `inputValue.trim() == '' ||`  so in case no input is provided then it will not filter based on input.
- Similarly added `selectedGenres.length == 0 ||` , so if no `Genres` are selected for filter it will not filter with `Genres`.
- You can make same condition for `selectedYear` also, as I can't assume what could be its default value, I have not added such condition.
- Used `.ToLowerCase` in condition so it will show results in case insensitive manner.

```js
let videoList = [
{id: 501437, artist: "Bob", title: "All In", release_year: 2014, genre_id: 14},
{id: 501649, artist: "Elina", title: "Veni paca to", release_year: 2014, genre_id: 8},
{id: 501895, artist: "Timbo", title: "I Should Have Known It", release_year: 2010, genre_id: 8},
{id: 502139, artist: "Wakanda", title: "Grove St. Party", release_year: 2011, genre_id: 6},
{id: 502992, artist: "Beyoncé", title: "Single Ladies (Put a Ring on It)", release_year: 2008, genre_id: 62}]

const selectedYear = [];
const inputValue = 'bob';
const selectedGenres = [14, 6, 8];

const filterRequirements = (data) => {  
  return (selectedYear == null || selectedYear == 0 || (Array.isArray(selectedYear) && selectedYear.length == 0) || data.release_year == selectedYear)
          && (inputValue.trim() == '' || data.artist.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()) || data.title.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()))
          && (selectedGenres.length == 0 || selectedGenres.includes(data.genre_id));
}

const filteredVideos = videoList.filter(filterRequirements);

console.log(filteredVideos);
```

Comment: But this aint working when I 'only' type inputfield or select genres

Comment: `selectedYear` is an array? Then how could its value be 2014?

Comment: props.....when someone select dropdown it will pass a year

Answer (score 0):

```
const videos = [
    {id: 501437, artist: "Bob", title: "All In", release_year: 2014, genre_id: 14 },
    {id: 501649, artist: "Elina", title: "Veni paca to", release_year: 2014, genre_id: 8 },
    {id: 501895, artist: "Timbo", title: "I Should Have Known It", release_year: 2010, genre_id: 8 },
    {id: 502139, artist: "Wakanda", title: "Grove St. Party", release_year: 2011, genre_id: 6 },
    {id: 502992, artist: "Beyoncé", title: "Single Ladies (Put a Ring on It)", release_year: 2008, genre_id: 62 },
];

const selectedYear = 2011;
const inputValue = 'grove';
const selectedGenres = new Set([14, 6, 8]);

const filteredVideos = videos
.filter((video) => video.release_year === selectedYear)
.filter((video) => video.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
.filter((video) => selectedGenres.has(video.genre_id));

console.log(filteredVideos);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach of having separate functions for each filter operation. This will make the actual filtering much easier to read and understand, in my opinion.

Something like this:

```js
const myArr = [
  {id: 501437, artist: "Bob", title: "All In", release_year: 2014, genre_id: 14 },
  {id: 501649, artist: "Elina", title: "Veni paca to", release_year: 2014, genre_id: 8 },
  {id: 501895, artist: "Timbo", title: "I Should Have Known It", release_year: 2010, genre_id: 8 },
  {id: 502139, artist: "Wakanda", title: "Grove St. Party", release_year: 2011, genre_id: 6 },
  {id: 502992, artist: "Beyoncé", title: "Single Ladies (Put a Ring on It)", release_year: 2008, genre_id: 62 },
];

const byYear = (year = 0, item) => (item.release_year === year);
const byArtist = (artist = '', item) => (item.artist === artist)
const byGenres = (genres = [], item) => (genres.includes(item.genre_id))

const filteredArr = myArr
  .filter(byYear.bind(this, 2014))
  .filter(byArtist.bind(this, 'Bob'))
  .filter(byGenres.bind(this, [14,6,8]));

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Comment: But this aint working when I 'only' type inputfield or select genres

Comment: @ncxcnb That was an example code. But if you want to filter something else, then of course you omit the filters you don't want to use

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think there's a 'one liner' solution. One possibility:

```js
const selectedYear = 2014;
const inputValue = "bob";
const selectedGenres = [14, 6, 8];

const checkYear = (data, year) => {
  return year ? data.release_year === year : true;
};
const checkValue = (data, value) => {
  return value
    ? data.artist.includes(value) || data.title.includes(value)
    : true;
};
const checkGenre = (data, genres) => {
  return genres ? genres.includes(data.genre_id) : true;
};

const filterRequirements = (data) =>
  checkYear(data, selectedYear) &&
  checkValue(data, inputValue) &&
  checkGenre(data, selectedGenres);

const filteredVideos = videoList.filter(filterRequirements);
```

Up to you how much you want to abstract to separate functions.

Edit: the other solutions with multiple `.filter()` might be better!

Comment: Complexity-wise it might be better to not filter the entire data set for each criteria but rather reduce the result set incrementally.